# Getting BIOS Serial Number without WMI

Tags: windows-xp, bios, serial-number

I'm attempting to get the serial number of the BIOS for a WinXP Embedded 32-bit system from a Win32 user mode application (MFC if that makes any diff).

I'm trying to get the same serial number that you can get via WMI from the 'Win32_BIOS' class from member "SerialNumber." The problem is that I can't use WMI as this will have to run on older systems that don't have WMI installed.

We basically have a series of machines with data encoded in this BIOS field so it can't be changed by the users, and we sometimes need this information to be output to a file and sent to us.

I've found 'GetSystemFirmwareTable', but the minimum Win version is WinXP 64-bit. WMI is out of the question, and we already have code to read it from a directly mapped physical address, but the problem is that the software we use that allows us to map those physical addresses is tied to our software, and our software cannot run at this stage in this particular use case (licensing).

As far as I've found, the only other way to map a physical hardware address from a user-mode application is to delve into driver territory and integrate some driver libraries into the application to allow it to map physical addresses.

Is there some kind of shadow copy that the OS makes that I can access without a huge amount of configuration?

Answer (score 1):

NTVDM in Windows XP map the first MiB of physical memory so you should be able to find the [SMBIOS](http://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios/) blob in that first megabyte and get the BIOS serial number from there.  See the [PDF specification](http://www.dmtf.org/standards/published_documents/DSP0134_2.6.0.pdf) for further reference.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Following the specification, I still have to access the hardware address of 0x000f0000, which means that my user mode application needs to be able to map it to a virtual address, which I can't do at the moment (as far as I know) because of what I said above.

Isn't ntvdm the process that runs 16-bit DOS applications on the current versions of Windows? Are you suggesting that I should write a 16-bit DOS application so I can read from it's copy of the SMBIOS data?

Comment: Yes, that was what I was thinking about.  Drop a MS-DOS COM-file and run it from your Windows application and write the SMBIOS data to a file using INT 0x21 which you then can collect from your user mode application.

Comment: Hmm, a good idea, but I actually found sample code for an app by sysinternals.com to map physical memory:

http://nah6.com/~itsme/cvs-xdadevtools/itsutils/src/sysint-physmem.cpp

I was able to adapt this to do exactly what I wanted, quite easily. But it only works on XP, which for me is fine, that's all I need it for, because on anything higher, we'll probably end up using WMI because it's just easier and comes with the OS.