# retrieve serialnumber remotely

Tags: wmi, serial-number

Im trying to create a program or a script to remotely retrieve all the hardwares (computers, printers etc) serialnumbers and I was just wondering if WMI is necessary.

I do know about the basic

```
wmic /NODE: "Computername" bios get serialnumber
```

but this also creates some problems with access as you need administrator rights on both computers if I have understood it correctly and also that the remote computer is configured to allow incoming WMI request.

Is it necessary to use WMI for this or are there any other ways to go about this? I know that WMI knows anything you might want to know about a computer but Im interested in the serialnumber only for now, and only on windows enviroments aswell I might add.

So if there are any Im looking for tips on any other way around this besides using WMI as it causes alot of other challenges and the goal is to keep it as simple as possible for the user.

Comment: What programming language do you want use to retrieve such info?

Comment: Well those ive worked in sofar that I feel "comfortable" to use is primarily C#, java and javascript but Im open to trying new languages if they provide any benefit over thos Ive mentioned. Im more focused on the problem then the language I end up using.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835483/getting-bios-serial-number-without-wmi

Answer (score 1):

Add the user switch to prompt an administrative login,

wmic /USER: Administrator /NODE: "Computername" bios get serialnumber

Also Remote Administration must be allowed on the target node firewall or it will fail, administrator or not

Comment: NOTE: The (") that surround the computer name are not needed unless the computer name is something like Office-PC, in that example you would type "Office-PC", if for example it were simply Office you would not need the (") surrounding the name although it would still work; this is useful information if you were checking the serial number on 100+ machines from a remote location, saves lots of typing :)